# Habiliar Menus de MDI Parent

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas tardes a todos, tengo la siguiente duda existencial, tengo un **formulario MDI Parent de WindowsForms**, en el cual muestro una serie de ventanas, pero en el evento **Load** necesito cargar un **formulario de Login**, el cual, al presionar el **boton Validar**, si el usuario esta *correctamente autenticado habilite los menus*, cierre el **form del Login** y pueda ejecutar las diferentes aplicaciones, el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
public void MuestraLogin()
{
    frmLogin objLogin = new frmLogin();
    objLogin.MdiParent = this;
    objLogin.Show();
}
public void InhabilitaMenus()
{
    try
    {
        menuStrip1.Enabled = false;
        menuStrip1.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
public void ObtenerValidacion(bool valido)
{
    try
    {
        if (Valido)
        {
            menuStrip1.Visible = true;
            menuStrip1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
private void frmMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MuestraLogin();
    InhabilitaMenus();           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Por lo general, se considera el logueo antes de permitir mostrar las pantallas principales, por ejemplo: contenedor, menus, etc.

---

Considerando tu caso podrías modificar:

**frmLogin:**

```
// Creando variable del formulario que contiene el menú
readonly frmMenu frmPrincipal;

// Modificar constructor para referenciar al formulario que contiene el menú
public frmLogin(frmMenu principal)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    frmPrincipal = principal;
}

// Evento click de tu botón que valida
private void btnValidad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmPrincipal.ObtenerValidacion(true);
    this.Close();
}
```

**frmMenu:**

```
// Pasar por parámetro el formulario que contiene el menú
public void MuestraLogin()
{
    frmLogin objLogin = new frmLogin(this);
    objLogin.MdiParent = this;
    objLogin.Show();
}
```

Donde, **frmPrincipal** es el *nombre de la clase* que contiene los menús.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no metería lógica que tenga que ver con el formulario principal en el formulario de login. Si es un formulario de login la lógica interna debería ser exclusivamente para eso: para validar el usuario.

Yo lo que haría es mostrar el formulario de login como un diálogo y que éste devolviera un valor indicando si la validación ha tenido éxito o no.

El código del botón aceptar del formulario de login podría ser algo así:

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = ValidarUsuario()
        ? DialogResult.Yes
        : DialogResult.No;
    Close();
}
```

Si la validación del usuario es correcta el formulario devuelve `DialogResult.Yes`, de otra forma devuelve `DialogResult.No`.

En el formulario MDI principal podrías abrir este diálogo como:

```
private void frmMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InhabilitarMenus();
    var login = new frmLogin();
    var usuarioValido = login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes;
    ObtenerValidacion(usuarioValido);
}
```

Después de inhabilitar los menús se muestra el formulario de login con `ShowDialog` y el usuario se considera válido si este formulario devuelve un resultado `DialogResult.Yes`. Con esta información ya podrías llamar al método `ObtenerValidacion`.